# Shortcode is not working in wordpress 3.0

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Is there anything need to enable for shortcode to work in Wordpress 3.0? I have tried some short codes and none of them working as expected.

regards - dj

Comment: Nope, shortcodes work as they always have. Can you clarify what 'not working as expected' means; perhaps you have some incompatible plugin/theme code interfering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short codes are as simple or as complex as you intend them to be. Also they can solve some pretty annoying problems and add a lot of functionality for your users. One thing I always use a short code for is embedding YouTube videos and media of the same format.

Here are some links that may help you:

- [Google Maps Short Code](http://digwp.com/2010/01/google-maps-shortcode/) - by Chris Coyier @ http://www.digwp.com/
- [Short Code API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) - WordPress Codex page about
  short codes

Comment: Thanks!!! These were useful links. But contact form short code is not working in my wordpress 3.0. For that do I need to enable any plugin?

Comment: yeh you need to enable the plugin that creates the shortcode function behind the scenes

Answer (score 2):

If its a template file you are trying to put them into you will need to put the code into a function and display it like:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="448" title="Contact"]' ); ?>
```

I am guessing you have it all sorted by now though as I have just checked when this was posted.

Answer (score 1):

Plus make sure you call the following function

```
the_content()
```

to output your content